# SpeechBrain: Cannot Load Pretrained Model from Local Path

Tags: speech-recognition, speech-to-text, torch, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers

I'm trying to load a pretrained SpeechBrain HuggingFace model from local files; I don't want it to call out to HuggingFace to download. However, unless I change the `pretrained_path` in `hyperparams.yaml`, it is still calling out to HuggingFace and downloading the models from HF.

```
from speechbrain.pretrained import EncoderClassifier
model_folder = "/local/path/to/folder/with/model_files"
model = EncoderClassifier.from_hparams(source=model_folder)
```

To get the model files into a local directory:

1. I downloaded the model from HuggingFace.
2. I moved the actual model files in `~/.cache/huggingface/hub/` to `model_folder` path. I also renamed them to their symlinked names: `embedding_model.ckpt`, `label_encoder.ckpt`, and `classifier.ckpt`.
3. I then tried changing `pretrained_path` in `hyperparams.yaml` to `model_folder`. But that causes the model to not load properly.

HF model: https://huggingface.co/TalTechNLP/voxlingua107-epaca-tdnn

What's the right way to load an `EncoderClassifier` from local files?

Comment: I think the question would benefit from having only `speechbrain` as tag rather than speech recogntion, hugging face, etc. These configs are specific of SpeechBrain toolkit :)

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: User Error. The steps in 1-3 above work. There was a typo in the names of one of my files: it should be `label_encoder.txt` not `label_encoder.ckpt`. You can see this by looking at `hyperparams.yaml` for `voxlingua107-epaca-tdnn` to see what it expects.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding my 10 cents as a SpeechBrain newbie, hope it helps other people.

For me the model was another ECAPA-TDNN, but for [emotion recognition on IEMOCAP](https://github.com/speechbrain/speechbrain/blob/develop/recipes/IEMOCAP/emotion_recognition/hparams/train.yaml) instead of LID on VoxLingua107. Besides, the model was on [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1U9SiO4KkCNBKfxilXzJqBZ_k-vHz4ltV?usp=sharing) rather than on HF hub.

First thing was to move files `hyperparams.yaml` and `label_encoder.txt` to the checkpoints dir `save/CKPT+2021-07-04+12-04-23+00/`, and then editing the YAML config file as follows. The bottomline secret is to link some `*.ckpt` files to the `pretrained` param, tho.

```
# this param should be edited
pretrained_path: /tmp/ECAPA-TDNN/1968/save/CKPT+2021-07-04+12-04-23+00

# the following must be appended
label_encoder: !new:speechbrain.dataio.encoder.CategoricalEncoder

pretrainer: !new:speechbrain.utils.parameter_transfer.Pretrainer
    loadables:
        embedding_model: !ref <embedding_model>
        classifier: !ref <classifier>
        mean_var_norm: !ref <mean_var_norm>
        label_encoder: !ref <label_encoder>
    paths:
        embedding_model: !ref <pretrained_path>/embedding_model.ckpt
        classifier: !ref <pretrained_path>/classifier.ckpt
        mean_var_norm: !ref <pretrained_path>/normalizer.ckpt
        label_encoder: !ref <pretrained_path>/label_encoder.txt
```

Then I wrote the Python script that performs inference on a single file.

```py
from speechbrain.pretrained import EncoderClassifier
model_folder = "/tmp/ECAPA-TDNN/1968/save/CKPT+2021-07-04+12-04-23+00"
model = EncoderClassifier.from_hparams(source=model_folder)
x = model.classify_file("/tmp/angry.wav")
print(x)  # (tensor([[0.4100, 0.3910, 0.2401, 0.7020]]), tensor([0.7020]), tensor([3]), ['neu'])
```

One's also gotta make sure that the class from [`speechbrain.pretrained`'s interfaces](https://github.com/speechbrain/speechbrain/blob/develop/speechbrain/pretrained/interfaces.py) matches the model's.

Links that helped me:

- https://huggingface.co/speechbrain/emotion-recognition-wav2vec2-IEMOCAP/blob/main/hyperparams.yaml#L49
- https://huggingface.co/TalTechNLP/voxlingua107-epaca-tdnn/blob/main/hyperparams.yaml#L44
- https://github.com/speechbrain/speechbrain/issues/1226